# Can someone tell me if there is a syntax for what I would like to do in swift

Tags: swift

I have a class like this one:

```
class Currency {
    let code: String
    let country: String
}
```

I have a segment control.
When the 1st segment is pressed, I want the **code**, when the 2nd segment is pressed, I want the **country**

I'm checking it quite often in my code with:

```
self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? currency.country : currency.code
```

Is there a way to declare a constant with it like

```
let choice = self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? currency.country : currency.code
```

knowing that at the time of declaration, I haven't created `currency` yet and then, when I'm calling it, I could do for example

```
let char = first(currency.choice)
```

or something like it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could put it in a method or [computed property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html). For a computed property, you could add this to whatever class contains the `segment` instance variable:

```
let choice: String {
    return segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? currency.country : currency.code
}
```

(This assumes that class also contains a `currency` instance variable.)

Comment: Yes I thought about the computed property but the thing is that currency comes from a list of Currency objects. How can I know when I'm calling my computed property, which object from the list I'm talking about?